# Design tab is not showing up in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm having a problem with Powerpoint. The Design tab is not showing. But on other computer that tab is showing. This is a screenshot of the other PC

[image]

and mine

[image]

How to show this tab?

Comment: Isn't the design tab there on both screenshots? Maybe I misunderstood and you mean it doesn't open up when you click it? — Either way, this seems more like a question you should ask Microsoft support.

Comment: In first screenshot there is two design tab and lot of feature available in that. I mean when i create any shape and click on that shape then another desing option shows and under that option lot of other similar design are showing. But this feature is not available in mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are talking about because both tabs are there.

But remember that some features are context sensitive. Some are activated when you select an object, an image, a smart content.

And some other tabs are plug-ins.

You can customize a ribbon bar: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31

Comment: Please check both screenshot. On first one design tab is showing before format tab. But in second snapshot design tab is not showing.